# MySQL use date() in CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, case

I am trying to use the date() function in MySQL to use only the date from a datetime format to create cases for total number of orders based on day of the week. However, when I run this query, I get a value of '0' for each case.

```
select 
(CASE datetime WHEN date(datetime) = '2020-06-22' THEN count(order_id) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mon'
,(CASE datetime WHEN date(datetime) = '2020-06-23' THEN count(order_id) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Tue'
,(CASE datetime WHEN date(datetime) = '2020-06-24' THEN count(order_id) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Wed'
,(CASE datetime WHEN date(datetime) = '2020-06-25' THEN count(order_id) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Thu'
,(CASE datetime WHEN date(datetime) = '2020-06-26' THEN count(order_id) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fri'
from table;
```

I confirmed I do get my desired ouput for an individual date when I run the following query.

```
select count(order_id) 
from table
where date(datetime) = '2020-06-22';
```

Comment: - do you want to have the result in one row or one row for each weekday

Comment: @BerndBuffen I want to have the result in one row, with a column for each weekday.

Comment: Don't you need a `GROUP BY` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tray a query like this:

```
select
sum( if( weekday(datetime) = 0,1,0)) as 'Mon',
sum( if( weekday(datetime) = 1,1,0)) as 'Tue',
sum( if( weekday(datetime) = 2,1,0)) as 'Wed',
sum( if( weekday(datetime) = 3,1,0)) as 'Thu',
sum( if( weekday(datetime) = 4,1,0)) as 'Fri',
sum( if( weekday(datetime) = 5,1,0)) as 'Sat',
sum( if( weekday(datetime) = 6,1,0)) as 'Sun'

;
```

and you can use a

```
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2020-06-22' AND '2020-06-26'
```

if you want to get a range of dates

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a nice feature where boolean values are treated as numbers, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  So you can express the logic as:

```
select sum( weekday(datetime) = 0 ) as Mon,
       sum( weekday(datetime) = 1 ) as Tue,
       sum( weekday(datetime) = 2 ) as Wed,
       sum( weekday(datetime) = 3 ) as Thu,
       sum( weekday(datetime) = 4 ) as Fri,
       sum( weekday(datetime) = 5 ) as Sat,
       sum( weekday(datetime) = 6 ) as Sun
```

Or:

```
select sum( date(datetime) = '2020-06-22' ) as Mon,
       sum( date(datetime) = '2020-06-23' ) as Tue,
       sum( date(datetime) = '2020-06-24' ) as Wed,
       sum( date(datetime) = '2020-06-25' ) as Thu,
       sum( date(datetime) = '2020-06-26' ) as Fri,
       sum( date(datetime) = '2020-06-27' ) as Sat,
       sum( date(datetime) = '2020-06-28' ) as Sun
```

Your query doesn't work because it is an aggregation query (the `COUNT()`) but you have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  MySQL should be returning a parsing error -- and the most recent version does.

I also strongly discourage you from using single quotes to delimit columns.  Here are three reasons:

- Your column names are fine and don't need to be escaped.
- Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.
- Backticks can be used if the identifiers do need to be escaped.